# Diart (torchaudio) on Windows x64 results in torchaudio error "ImportError: FFmpeg libraries are not found. Please install FFmpeg."

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, torchaudio, diarization

I am giving a try to a speech *diarization* project named [**diart**](https://github.com/juanmc2005/diart)
(based on [hugging face](https://huggingface.co/) models)

I follow the instructions using a `miniconda` environment which are essentially:

```
conda create -n diart python=3.8
conda activate diart
conda install portaudio pysoundfile ffmpeg -c conda-forge
pip install diart
# + register some pyannote stuff on hugging face
# requiring hugging face CLI instructions for API token
```

However, I keep bumping into python import error:

> ImportError: FFmpeg libraries are not found. Please install FFmpeg.

Trace:

```
>>> from diart.sources import MicrophoneAudioSource
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_extension.py", line 71, in _init_ffmpeg
    _load_lib("libtorchaudio_ffmpeg")
  File "F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_extension.py", line 52, in _load_lib
    torch.ops.load_library(path)
  File "F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart\lib\site-packages\torch\_ops.py", line 573, in load_library
    ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart\Lib\site-packages\torchaudio\lib\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg.pyd' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart\lib\site-packages\diart\sources.py", line 11, in <module>
    from torchaudio.io import StreamReader
  File "F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\io\__init__.py", line 21, in __getattr__
    torchaudio._extension._init_ffmpeg()
  File "F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_extension.py", line 73, in _init_ffmpeg
    raise ImportError("FFmpeg libraries are not found. Please install FFmpeg.") from err
ImportError: FFmpeg libraries are not found. Please install FFmpeg.
```

It is my first time with Torch, and I do believe the issue is with a missing TorchAudio specific library.

The python file that raises the exception states:

```py
def _init_ffmpeg(): # line 60
    # ...
    try:
        _load_lib("libtorchaudio_ffmpeg")
    except OSError as err:
        raise ImportError("FFmpeg libraries are not found. Please install FFmpeg.") from err #<=== line 73 : the exception
    # ...
```

*Below you will find many details concerning the environment.*

## **Question**

**Am I missing something ? What should I do to use this project ?**

---

## Additionnal info

The resulting environment setup (using Miniconda Powershell) in admin mode.

FFMPEG is confirmed in the path to be seen from the conda env install:

```
(diart) PS C:\Windows\system32> get-command ffmpeg

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     ffmpeg.exe                                         0.0.0.0    F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart\Library\bin\ffmpeg.exe
```

### Python

```
(diart) PS C:\Windows\system32> python --version
Python 3.8.16
```

### Conda env setup

```
(diart) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda --version
conda 23.3.1

(diart) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda list

# packages in environment at F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
aiohttp                   3.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
aiosignal                 1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
alembic                   1.10.4                   pypi_0    pypi
antlr4-python3-runtime    4.9.3                    pypi_0    pypi
aom                       3.5.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
asteroid-filterbanks      0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
async-timeout             4.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     23.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
audioread                 3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
backports-cached-property 1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                h8ffe710_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.12.7            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
cachetools                5.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2022.12.7                pypi_0    pypi
cffi                      1.15.1           py38h57701bc_3    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
cmaes                     0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
colorlog                  6.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
commonmark                0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
contourpy                 1.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 5.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
diart                     0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
docopt                    0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
einops                    0.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
expat                     2.5.0                h63175ca_1    conda-forge
ffmpeg                    5.1.2           gpl_h5b1d025_106    conda-forge
filelock                  3.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.2               hbde0cde_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.39.3                   pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.12.1               h546665d_1    conda-forge
frozenlist                1.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
fsspec                    2023.4.0                 pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               2.17.3                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
greenlet                  2.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.54.0                   pypi_0    pypi
hmmlearn                  0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
huggingface-hub           0.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
hyperpyyaml               1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.4                      pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        6.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-resources       5.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         h57928b3_46319    conda-forge
joblib                    1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
julius                    0.2.7                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
lame                      3.100             hcfcfb64_1003    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              16_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              16_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.5.0                h63175ca_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h8ffe710_5    conda-forge
libflac                   1.4.2                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libhwloc                  2.9.1                h51c2c0f_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0              16_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h19919ed_0    conda-forge
librosa                   0.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
libsndfile                1.2.0                h2628c91_0    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.40.0               hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.10.4               hc3477c8_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hcfcfb64_4    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.39.1                   pypi_0    pypi
mako                      1.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2022.1.0           h6a75c08_874    conda-forge
mpg123                    1.31.3               h63175ca_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
multidict                 6.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
networkx                  2.8.8                    pypi_0    pypi
numba                     0.56.4                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.23.5                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
omegaconf                 2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
openh264                  2.3.1                h63175ca_2    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.0                hcfcfb64_2    conda-forge
optuna                    3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 23.1                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    9.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       23.1.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pooch                     1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
portaudio                 19.6.0               h63175ca_7    conda-forge
primepy                   1.3                      pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.20.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pthreads-win32            2.9.1                hfa6e2cd_3    conda-forge
pyannote-audio            2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyannote-core             4.5                      pypi_0    pypi
pyannote-database         4.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pyannote-metrics          3.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyannote-pipeline         2.3                      pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydeprecate               0.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.8.16          h4de0772_1_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python_abi                3.8                      3_cp38    conda-forge
pytorch-lightning         1.6.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pytorch-metric-learning   1.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2023.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0                      pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.29.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
resampy                   0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
rich                      12.6.0                   pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.9                      pypi_0    pypi
ruamel-yaml               0.17.21                  pypi_0    pypi
ruamel-yaml-clib          0.2.7                    pypi_0    pypi
rx                        3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
semver                    2.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sentencepiece             0.1.98                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                67.7.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
shellingham               1.5.0.post1              pypi_0    pypi
simplejson                3.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
singledispatchmethod      1.0                      pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sortedcontainers          2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sounddevice               0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
soundfile                 0.10.3.post1             pypi_0    pypi
speechbrain               0.5.14                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlalchemy                2.0.11                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.40.0               hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
svt-av1                   1.4.1                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tabulate                  0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tbb                       2021.9.0             h91493d7_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               2.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
torch                     1.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
torch-audiomentations     0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
torch-pitch-shift         1.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
torchmetrics              0.11.4                   pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.65.0                   pypi_0    pypi
typer                     0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2023.3                   pypi_0    pypi
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.15                  pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.3                h3d8a991_11    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.34.31931         h4c5c07a_11    conda-forge
websocket-client          1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
websocket-server          0.6.4                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.40.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
x264                      1!164.3095           h8ffe710_2    conda-forge
x265                      3.5                  h2d74725_3    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h8d14728_0    conda-forge
yarl                      1.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
zipp                      3.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
```

---

## Things I tried

Follow PyTorch audio build process as described [here](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/build.windows.html) using Visual Studio 2022 Community powershell for developper x64

```
Enter-VsDevShell 7c1743f6 -Arch amd64 # if necessary, for Visual Studio build tools x64 within power shell for developpers
# 
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/audio
cd audio
set USE_FFMPEG=1
# python setup.py develop
python setup.py develop --verbose
```

Output error slightly truncated due to post size overflow (30_000 char):

```
# redacted due to post char limit...
rir.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) class at::Tensor __cdecl at::fft_irfft(class at::Tensor const &,class c10::optional<__int64>,__int64,class c10::optional<class c10::basic_string_view<char> >)" (__imp_?fft_irfft@at@@YA?AVTensor@1@AEBV21@V?$optional@_J@c10@@_JV?$optional@V?$basic_string_view@D@c10@@@4@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "void __cdecl torchaudio::rir::`anonymous namespace'::make_rir_filter_impl<float>(class at::Tensor &,double,__int64,class at::Tensor &)" (??$make_rir_filter_impl@M@?A0xcc00d006@rir@torchaudio@@YAXAEAVTensor@at@@N_J0@Z)
torchaudio\csrc\libtorchaudio.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 12 externes non résolus
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

---

## Tests

### 1. @Brock Brown ==> what if `conda uninstall ffmpeg` ?

```
(diart) PS C:\Windows\system32> conda uninstall ffmpeg
(diart) PS C:\Windows\system32> python
Python 3.8.16 (default, Mar  2 2023, 03:18:16) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from diart.sources import *

  # redacted due to post char limit...
    from _sounddevice import ffi as _ffi
  File "F:\DEV\miniconda3\envs\diart\lib\site-packages\_sounddevice.py", line 2, in <module>
    import _cffi_backend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
```

```
(diart) PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Command ffmpeg

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     ffmpeg.exe                                         1.0.0.0    C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\ffmpeg.exe


(diart) PS C:\Windows\system32> ffmpeg --version
ffmpeg version 6.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

---

### FFMPEG version

according to [this link](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/tutorials/streamwriter_basic_tutorial.html) it may be preferrable to use ffmpeg <4.4.

I tried that using chocolatey install ffmpeg=4.3 without success.

Comment: Something curious that I noticed that might push you in the right direction, in your conda environment listing, your ffmpeg is listed as follows:
`ffmpeg 5.1.2`
Whereas your `get-command ffmpeg` yielded
`ffmpeg 0.0.0.0`, maybe these are separate installations that are somehow conflicting with each other in a weird way? What happens when you do those same commands after attempting to uninstall ffmpeg from your conda?

Comment: test added at end of the question.(note: the conda uninstall had several conda "upgrades/downgrades/superseeded" consequences...)

Comment: Yikes. I meant to ask about the results of `get_command ffmpeg` also, I was curious to see if that `ffmpeg 0.0.0.0` was there still after uninstalling, since they were displayed as two different versions. (even though 0.0.0.0 doesn't really seem like a version, seems like a bug or something)

Comment: fixed post; 0.0.0.0 seems a powershell get-command specific output (based in file metadata ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TorchAudio 0.13.1 supports FFmpeg v4.1 - v4.4. You have FFmpeg 5.1.
Installing FFmpeg v4 should resolve the problem. (v4.3 or v4.4 is better).

Comment: This is an info lost in the editing process due to post size limitation but : I have already tried when I found [**that link** (you did not provide)](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/tutorials/streamwriter_basic_tutorial.html). Nevertheless, the issue _may_ not be ffmpeg itself, I _believe_ it is the torchaudio install that does not find its own appropriate library (my theory still has to be demonstrated). A complete answer with some proofs and link/references would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/installation.html#optional-dependencies

Comment: actually, this is more relevant to 0.13
https://github.com/pytorch/audio/releases/tag/v0.12.0
```
† To use StreamReader, FFmpeg libraries are required. Please install FFmpeg. The coverage of codecs depends on how these libraries are configured. TorchAudio official binaries are compiled to work with FFmpeg 4 libraries; FFmpeg 5 can be used if TorchAudio is built from source.
```

Comment: update your answer to be a little most self-sufficient (using intel from these comments), then I'll vote it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

conda install 'ffmpeg<4.4'

This installation helps to work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. I tried reducing the folder/pathname of the project and it worked for me.